# JQuery Transform CSS and invalid CSS property

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a doughnut with text around the inside. Currently I am trying to place each element inside the container around the circle using transform, but the value outputted is invalid and the JQuery CSS value won't appear.

Here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dm6owLp9/

The expected outcome is to apply a `transform` with a `rotate`, `translate` and another `rotate` value to each `p` tag positioning each element around the doughnut.

Current outcome is no `transform` value is being applied to any of the `p` tags.

On line 37 of the JQuery amending it to read:

```
'transform': 'rotate(' + rot * 1 + 'deg)'
```

Does apply the transform style to each element, so I assume the main issue lies on line 37 but I am unsure where I have gone wrong with that line. As doing a `console.log` of that shows what appears to me as an acceptable CSS value that being:

```
transform: rotate(96.66666666666667deg) translate(-335.83333333333337) rotate(-96.66666666666667deg);
```

If I then add that CSS value to one of the `p` tags the browser inspector reports this as an invalid CSS property.

As a side note I have achieved this effect using a SCSS mixin, but the number of items in the doughnut can vary and the size of the doughnut needs to expand and shrink.

Comment: That's because the value you are using in `translate()` is missing a unit.

Comment: Well I guess I need to go for an eye test as it was just missing a 'px' on line 37 of the JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Line 37 required a `PX` adding to the string to make the translate value valid.

```
'transform': 'rotate(' + rot * 1 + 'deg) translate(' + outerWidth / -2.4 + 'px' + ') rotate(' + rot * -1 + 'deg)'
```